# maxRequestLength not working though I changed in config change

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am working on one button click event in vb.net. When I click on that hyperlink I am getting "There was an exception running the extensions specified in the configfile. ---> Maximum request length exceeded"

I had gone through the similar questions on stack overflow and somehow I tried to change the maxRequestLength to 5000000 from initial value of 500000. First time it worked and from the next time onwards it's not working.

Below is my change:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" executionTimeout="420" maxRequestLength="50000000" />
```

Kindly help me on this please. Thank You!

Comment: My first question would be: why is your HTTP request so big? What's in there? Is this somehow related to SQL Server Reporting Service?

Comment: Thank you for the response , I am not sure about it @Ruud Helderman . It's a vast application though .

Comment: But for the first time when I extended the value it worked without any exception after that it's throwing same exception

Comment: Maybe your first request was under 50 MB, and later requests exceeded that limit? I don't know. Do you? If not, then please investigate. Use an HTTP sniffer like Fiddler or Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs , I am a beginner in this sector . I have no idea on Fiddler or Wireshark . Anyway I will go through it. Thanks again!

Comment: I just walked through this link : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4688/resolving-the-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception-in-sql-server-reporting-services/
Here it states that the .dll file is exceeding 4MB . The same is happening to me in 3-4 files. As you mentioned it is getting incremented and exceeding the limit.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to configuring the value of `maxRequestLength`, you also need to configure the value of `maxAllowedContentLength`:

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hello @samwu , Thanks for your inputs . Actually I am getting the exception at this line:
Dim cReturn As String = ES.MailService(cXML) --------(Firework application)
where this ES is an Email service (another application) and they're adding this service as a reference in current application (Firework) where I am getting this exception . Should I modify the web.config files of both the applications? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried either ways , I added  maxAllowedContentLength property as well as maxRequestLength in both the applications . But it's throwing the same exception still . Please help me on this .Thank You!

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I debugged the code and came to know that when the file's length is 3068072 bytes , it's not throwing exception but when the file's length is 4269825 bytes , it's throwing the exception . Uninterestingly both files are same but scenarios are different . I tried to overwrite the bytes length and it worked without any exception . How can I proceed on this ? Any Idea Sir?

Comment: maxAllowedContentLength property as well as maxRequestLength changes are not working though

Comment: Are you setting these two properties in iis? Can you share your web.config file?

Comment: Yes I am setting these properties in IIS.
It's not considering the entire web.config file here. Could you please tell me where can I share it?